# How to convert the following list to a dictionary?

Tags: c#, json, linq, .net-3.5

The following code:

```
var data = _context.People.ToList(); //_context is my DataContext.
```

produces the result:

```
[{ "name": "john", "age": "30" }, { "name": "jane", "age": "31" }]
```

but, I want it to be a dictionary, so something like:

```
{ "xldata" : [{ "name": "john", "age": "30" }, { "name": "jane", "age": "31" }] }
```

I got it to work by doing:

```
Dictionary<string,List<People>> vals = new Dictionary<string, List<People>>();
        vals.Add("xldata", people);
```

but, my dictionary's value is `System.Object[]` instead of the `people`

The purpose of this is to export data, so when I get to this line:

```
var people = jss.Deserialize<List<People>>(args["xldata"]);

args["xldata"] is `System.Object[]` and it says `Invalid JSON primitive`.
```

Here is the script is supposed to export the data to excel:

```
$.post(urlContent + exportHandlerPath, Json, function(data) {
        var viewData = {};
        viewData.xldata = JSON.stringify(data);
        html = ich.excelExportTemplate(viewData);
        $excelExportContainer.html(html);
        var input = $excelExportContainer.find('input#excelExportHiddenField');
        input.val(viewData.xldata);

        var $excelForm = $('#excelExportForm');

        $excelForm.attr('action', '/People/ExportToExcel/');
        $excelForm.submit();
    }
```

Comment: Do you want "name" to be the key and "age" to be the value?

Comment: What properties do you want to use for the keys and values?

Comment: I'm confused - your "key" is an array of `People`?

Comment: I assume that you are using WCF Data Services or something like that? LINQ to Objects or Entity Framework wouldn't be returning JSON..

Comment: @evanmcdonnal, I modified my post.

Comment: @TimB - No WCF, I am using Linq to Entities.

Comment: @Xaisoft it looks like you answered your question?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal, but it is confusing to me because I expect to see the key and the people data, not System.Object[]

Comment: Where do you "see" System.Object[]? It would be nice to see how you're trying to consume this.

Comment: @Xaisoft I'm not sure exactly why you're getting objects back instead of Persons but I would look in a few places; 1) make sure there is a Person class that implements a data contract so that EF knows to deserialize rows for the People table into Person objects. 2) try implicit and explicit casts. It's possible the compiler can't infer the type of data so it defaults to object.

Comment: did you try ` vals.Add("xldata", data )` ?

Comment: What's the data type of the 'People' property in your data context type? Me thinks its an enumerable of 'object' items like 'IEnumerable<object>' or 'object[]'.

Comment: There is the 'ToDictionary' extension method that should be available for all enumerable types, Have you looked at that?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal - I modified the post to include the script.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your args["xldata"] does not contain a json string like [{ "name": "john", "age": "30" }, { "name": "jane", "age": "31" }], but something returned by a .net object .ToString().

With JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize you can only deserialize json represenations.